# Jquery Load onclick breaks on segond load after page is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a code that loads pages onclick but after the page is loaded once, the segond time when i click on a link from the loaded div for it to load another thing or the same thing, it does not load it but it rather leads me directly to the page.

Here is my jquery code to load the page

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $('a[rel*=charger_tout]').on('click', function() {

        var myId_to_update_here = $(this).data('ajax');

        var afficher_chargement = $(this).data('icon');

        if(afficher_chargement=='Oui')
        {
            $('#'+myId_to_update_here).html('<img src="images/facebook_style_loader.gif" />');
        }
        //Fin de l'affichage du chargement si le data-icon='Oui'



      $('#'+myId_to_update_here).load($(this).attr('href'), function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if(textStatus == 'error') {

                    $('#'+myId_to_update_here).html('<p>Oupps.. There was an error making the AJAX request. Maybe your internet connection is slowing down.</p>');
                }
            });

      return false;
    });
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

});
```

And here is the link that enables me to load a page containing another link that i want to load again onclick

`<a href="brouillons.php?membre=max" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data-icon="Oui">charger_tout</a>`

When i click for the first time it loads but when i click on the loaded link, it does not load with ajax but it takes me to the page. How to solve that ?

I am using **Jquery in noConflict** Mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the second link is added later and not in the DOM when the page is loaded, you can use `on()` to delegate the event from a static parent element. Instead of

```
$('a[rel*=charger_tout]').on('click', function() { ...
```

this would be (e.g.)

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[rel*=charger_tout]',  function() { ...
```

Instead of `$(document)` every parent element of `a` that is already in the DOM can be used.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I am using Jquery in noConflict mode (with prototype js) so when i use `$(document).on('click', 'a[rel*=charger_tout]',  function() { ` it just directs me to the page without performing any ajax request. 
Does it means that i have to add another jquery code to the page that is loaded ? 
Or do i have to replace every instance of `$(` with `$(document)` ?

Comment: @JohnMax No, you don't have to replace all instances. But before going into possible noConflict mode - issues: could you check if it works if you change it to `$(document).on('click', 'a[rel*=charger_tout]', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added elements are not recognized by `click()` function ( `click()` is a shortcut of `.on('click', function() { ... })` ).

On page load (first time), `click()` function works just fine because the clicked link was already in the DOM, but, on the second load, the newly added link is not recognized.

In your case you have to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[rel*=charger_tout', function() {
    // your code here ..
});
```

Comment: I am using jquery in noconflict mode so when i do that it does not load the page with ajax but it goes to the page as if it was just a mere link.